package javax.validation does not exist
I upgraded the springboot-starter-parent to 3.7.5 earlier it was working well with 2.7.5 but not now. Also I m getting error :
[ERROR] /home/dev/repo/ws/rbac-proxy/src/main/java/com/hpe/cnx/rbacproxy/validator/ValidateParamValue.java:[3,24] package javax.validation does not exist
[ERROR] /home/dev/repo/ws/rbac-proxy/src/main/java/com/hpe/cnx/rbacproxy/validator/ValidateParamValue.java:[4,24] package javax.validation does not exist
[ERROR] /home/dev/repo/ws/rbac-proxy/src/main/java/com/hpe/cnx/rbacproxy/validator/ValidateParamValue.java:[10,2] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Constraint
[ERROR] /home/dev/repo/ws/rbac-proxy/src/main/java/com/hpe/cnx/rbacproxy/validator/ValidateParamValue.java:[14,21] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Payload
[ERROR] /home/dev/repo/ws/rbac-proxy/src/main/java/com/hpe/cnx/rbacproxy/validator/ValidateRenameScopePayload.java:[4,24] package javax.validation does not exist
[ERROR] /home/dev/repo/ws/rbac-proxy/src/main/java/com/hpe/cnx/rbacproxy/validator/ValidateRenameScopePayload.java:[14,2] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Constraint
I had imported the javax. packages
I had added and removed various dependancy like :
Adding hibernates , validator-api , etc. still nothing worked

You mean probably Spring Boot 3.2.5 and not 3.7.5, right? You need to migrate from javax.validation to jakarta.validation. If you use JPA then also migrate from javax.peristence to jakarta.persistence. This has been changed between Spring Boot 2 and Spring Boot 3.

use jakarta validation instead of javax Validation
see : Spring Boot 3.0 package javax.validation does not exist

Java 17 has nothing to do with the migration to JakartaEE.
